# Expression about an "atmosphere of something" "a feeling of something"

Tags: questions

I went to a building and found out that the structure and decoration of the building are like art. I want to strenthen that the building has an "atmosphere of art" or "a feeling of art". I am wondering how native speakers express that. Can any friend help me?

Comment: Are you commenting on the architecture?  What do you mean by strenthen (strengthen? but strengthen doesn't fit the context)

Comment: @James K:Thanks you the comments, Jame. Yup, I am commenting on the architecture. Sorry about the confusion.  Please let me rephrase my questions. I am not sure about this sentence "The building has an atmosphere of art " , my main question is whether the expression "atmosphere of art" or "a feeling of art" is OK here. Or there are other expressions that fit better.

Comment: "atmosphere of..." or "feeling of..." are generally used with emotions or sensations ("atmosphere of terror", "feeling of loneliness"). I'm not totally sure what you mean by "atmosphere of art" - do you mean it brings to mind a particular work of art or style of art, or it seems as if it was created by an artist (because of its beauty or ornate construction or expressiveness), or it has some other quality it shares with art? You might say "it felt like a work of art" or "it reminded me of a work of art".

Comment: @StuartF: Hi Stuart, Thank you very much for explaining the using cases for atmosphere and feeling. Yes, I think it's expressiveness looks like a work of art. I think a work of art is a good way to describe what I want to say.

Answer (score 2):

To characterize the building as having very high artistic appeal, you might characterize it as a **piece of art** or a **work of art**, for example:

> The architecture of that building is so beautiful and intricate, it's a work of art.

You could also refer to it as a **masterpiece**.